# How do I call a stored procedure from js?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, stored-procedures

I know I can either create a node.js function or write a php script. But I am interested in calling stored procedure directly from plain js in clients browser. Lets say, client enters a connection string and a command to execute.

It's just for education, I know about security flaws when making a DB accessible from outside.

The question: is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I did search before asking. Creating an ActiveXObject means that solution is only for Internet Expolrer.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible communication with the outside world javascript has is what browser allows(and with many security restrictions): AJAX requests, websockets and general HTTP. As Postgres doesn’t have an api for these protocols, your challenge is impossible.